# Getting Error: "Please connect to a valid Azure HDInsight cluster before calling this cmdlet" while running Hive in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I have a **Azure HDInsight Cluster**. I want to run hive scripts in it through **Windows Powershell ISE**.

While running the following script in Powershell I am getting the following error.

**Script**:

```
$clusterName = "utsavdawncluster"
Use-AzureRmHDInsightCluster $clusterName
Invoke-Hive -Query "show tables;"
```

**Error**:

[image]

My Powershell versions are as follows:

[image]

**I am sure that the cluster name is correct and the cluster it is up and running.**

I am not able to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone please tell what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

# Set the cluster to use
 Use-AzureRmHDInsightCluster -ClusterName $clusterName -HttpCredential $creds

For a complete sample, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-hive-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

This is the query script I am using now and it is working fine!

```
$clusterName = "utsavdawncluster"
$creds=Get-Credential -Message "Enter the login for the cluster"
Use-AzureRmHDInsightCluster $clusterName -HttpCredential $creds
$queryString = "show tables;"
Invoke-AzureRmHDInsightHiveJob -Query $queryString
```

The only reason why it was not working before is the `Invoke-Hive` command. Now I am using `Invoke-AzureRmHDInsightHiveJob` and it is working fine.